# Where can a stale binary hide when developing an android app?

Tags: android, eclipse

*Guess I found it myself: Apparently the else-if block was detected as unreachable code and not compiled into the binary. At least that is my conclusion for now. It's almost 7am. Will further investigate after a little nap.*

I'm totally lost and lost a day already on digging really deep.

I have an android app. At some point, my changes could not be debugged anymore. It seamed to be running stale code. I've done all the obvious (Refresh, project clean), less obvious (eclipse -clean, fresh checkout of my project) and last thing I did was:

- download eclipse
- install mercurial and adt
- install android sdk
- checkout my project to a virgin workspace
- run the app in a newly created virtual device

guess what, it still behaves as follows:

When I put a breakpoint at "// breakpoint" pressing F6 (Step Over) I can step through "// 1" and "// 2" although after //1, //2 should be unreachable. Also the debugger knows nothing about the variables in the else-if block while I'm at //1

```
} else if (column == 4) { // breakpoint
    TextView cardSetLabel = (TextView) view;

    String name = cursor.getString(cardSetColumnIndex);
    name = name.substring(0, Math.min(15, name.length() - 1));
    cardSetLabel.setText(name); // 1
    return true;
}
return false; // 2
```

Actually even if I delete the whole surrounding code block, the stuff that it does still remains intact. This is voodoo, sorry.
At least deleting the whole Activity results in the Activity being gone at run time, so the theory of stuff being stale is not really an option.

Please, any help appreciated :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the else-if block was detected as unreachable code and not compiled into the binary. At least that is my conclusion for now.

Actually I had found out by debugging, that "4" is not the right number and actually a number that is never the value of "column" but I didn't expect the compiler to know that at compile time :(

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you're hitting //1 on one iteration and //2 on another? Maybe the enclosing method is called twice consecutively.

Maybe try uninstalling/installing with adb, typing paths in manually to be sure things are pointing where you think they are.  Check manually that your build directory is clean in between a clean and a fresh build.

Add a Log message in there, and watch for it in logcat to be sure you're running fresh code.

Comment: Iterations? No, I step pressing F6 (Step Over).
Uninstalling I tried, too but as that did not work, I installed it to a freshly created android virtual device, so pretty sure it is the latest creation of my eclipse.

logging was an obvious step that I skipped but tried now. I get no log output.

Answer (score 0):

Don't trust the debugger. Use some log statements to verify that the statements are actually being executed.

It is not uncommon for the debugger to get confused and step across lines that are not really being executed.

Add some new log statements at program start up. Your assumption that you are running stale code may be incorrect.

Comment: Yes, I may sound stupid and I'm close to video taping this as it is so ... gahhh. But even if I delete the whole code block from above the functionality stays in place.

Comment: Maybe try to build and install the project from the command line using ant. Make sure that eclipse isn't caching something in some secret place. You can do that by running "ant clean build debug" in the project directory.

Comment: Sorry here are better ant instructions. In the project directory run "android update project --path ." which will create your build.xml. Then run "ant clean" to clean the project. "ant debug" to compile a debug build and "ant install" to install it to your Android device.